# Type hint redis function python

Tags: python, redis

I tried different ways to type annotate the redis object and its method as below

```
foo.py
redis_instance: Any = redis.StrictRedis.from_url(url=REDIS_DB_URL, decode_responses=False)
```

```
config.py
REDIS_DB_URL: str | None = os.environ.get("REDIS_DB_URL")
```

```
.env
REDIS_DB_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
```

but stil getting error

```
 error: No overload variant of "from_url" of "Redis" matches argument types "Optional[str]", "bool"  [call-overload]
 
 note: Possible overload variants:
 note:     def [_StrType] from_url(cls, url: str, *, host: Optional[str] .... a big list
```

Comment: Looks like the URL can't be optional. Can you check you have the URL before making the call to `from_url`?

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks. Solved by setting default string instead of None.